# Contains is False but splitting does work

Tags: powershell

I was trying to find \bin in folder names.

The only solution was to split and see if more than one left.
E.g.

```
$t = "\csharp\azure\blob-quickstart\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1"
$t -split '\\bin'
```

more naturely is

```
$t.Contains("\\bin")
```

but that is False. Is there a smarter way to find Strings with backslashes in other Strings ?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned the `.Contains()` method does not use regex. So it should be `.Contains("\bin")` I think.

Comment: Yes, @Olaf is spot on. The regex pattern ``\\bin`` describes the literal string ``\bin`` - so the cognate `String.Contains()` call would be `$t.Contains("\bin")`

Comment: Thanks, I could swear I have tried also $t.Contains("\bin"). However that actually worked.